# When running this code on Quadratic solving I get these errors. (I am a student learning Java and stumped)

Tags: java

When running this code on Quadratic solving I get these errors. (I am a student learning Java and stumped)

```
public class Quadratic
{
public static double a;
public static double b;
public static double c;
public double bb;
public double ac;
public double negativeb;
public double bbac;
{
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 1;
}
public Quadratic() {
    
public Quadratic(int A, int B, int C) {
  a = A;
  b = B;
  c = C;
    }
public static boolean hasSoultions() {  
  if ( b*2 > 4*a*c) {
    return false;
}
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

public double getSoultion1() { 
  double sqrt = Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c));
  return (-b + sqrt)/(2*a);
}
public double getSolution2(){
  double sqrt = Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c));
  return (-b - sqrt)/(2*a);
}
}
//--------------------//
```

This is the runner
//--------------------//

```
    public class QuadraticRunner
{
  
  public static void main( String args [])
  {
    
    Quadratic test1 = new Quadratic (1, 5, 6);
    Quadratic test2 = new Quadratic (1, -4, 4);
    Quadratic test3 = new Quadratic (1, 0, 3);
    
    String equation1 = test1.toString();
        System.out.println(equation1);
    boolean hasSolution1 = test1.hasSolutions();
    double solution1 = test1.getSolution1();
    double solution1b = test1.getSolution2();
    String equation2 = test2.toString();
    boolean hasSolution2 = test2.hasSolutions();
    double solution2 = test2.getSolution1();
    double solution2b = test2.getSolution2();
    String equation3 = test3.toString();
    boolean hasSolution3 = test3.hasSolutions();
    double solution3 = test3.getSolution1();
    double solution3b = test3.getSolution2();
    
    
    System.out.println(equation1);
    System.out.println("Has real solutions: " + hasSolution1);
    System.out.println("Solution 1: " + solution1);
    System.out.println("Solution 2: " + solution1b);
    System.out.println("Expected solutions: -2.0, -3.0");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(equation2);
    System.out.println("Has real solutions: " + hasSolution2);
    System.out.println("Solution 1: " + solution2);
    System.out.println("Solution 2: " + solution2b);
    System.out.println("Expected solution: 2.0");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(equation3);
    System.out.println("Has real solutions: " + hasSolution3);
    System.out.println("Solution 1: " + solution3);
    System.out.println("Solution 2: " + solution3b);
    System.out.println("Expected solution: NaN");
  }
}
//----------------//
```

Here are the errors

```
//----------------//

    26 errors found:
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 17]
    Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 17]
    Error: Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 17]
    Error: Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 17]
    Error: Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 17]
    Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 22]
    Error: Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 22]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 22]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 31]
    Error: Syntax error on token "double", @ expected
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 31]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 31]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 35]
    Error: Syntax error on token "double", @ expected
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 35]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Documents\School\2 Second Period\DrJava\Quadratic.java  [line: 35]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 7]
    Error: The constructor Quadratic(int, int, int) is undefined
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 8]
    Error: The constructor Quadratic(int, int, int) is undefined
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 9]
    Error: The constructor Quadratic(int, int, int) is undefined
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 13]
    Error: The method hasSolutions() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 14]
    Error: The method getSolution1() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 15]
    Error: The method getSolution2() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 17]
    Error: The method hasSolutions() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 18]
    Error: The method getSolution1() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 19]
    Error: The method getSolution2() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 21]
    Error: The method hasSolutions() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 22]
    Error: The method getSolution1() is undefined for the type Quadratic
    File: C:\Users\jtann\Downloads\QuadraticRunner.java  [line: 23]
    Error: The method getSolution2() is undefined for the type Quadratic
```

Comment: `public static boolean hasSoultions()` this shouldn't be `static`, should it?

Comment: and you're nesting methods within constructors which is not allowed in Java.

Comment: Look at the first error message.  Go to the line number is specifies in the file it specifies.  On that line, what *specifically* are you doing?  It looks like you're trying to define a method inside of a constructor.  Why?  What is the goal of doing that?

Comment: More importantly, you should never see multiple errors like this, and that you do suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead, if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often** and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard-to-fix errors. Never try to add good code to bad.